# Test Garbage collection by finalize() function in Java, alive or dead?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

As you can see in the first block `SAVE_HOOK = null;` before going inside the if branch, I think `SAVE_HOOK == null`, so it should not go into `SAVE_HOOK.isAlive();`. But actually, I test it in the `Eclipse`:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Build id: 20170314-1500

Why does this happen?

```
public class FinalizeEscapeGC {

    public static FinalizeEscapeGC SAVE_HOOK = null;

    public void isAlive() {
        System.out.println("yes, i am still alive :)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println("finalize mehtod executed!");
        FinalizeEscapeGC.SAVE_HOOK = this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SAVE_HOOK = new FinalizeEscapeGC();

        // ---------------block 1----------------//
        SAVE_HOOK = null;
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if (SAVE_HOOK != null) {    // "SAVE_HOOK = null;"
            SAVE_HOOK.isAlive();    //  why the frist time it can go inside this if branch? 
        } else {
            System.out.println("no, i am dead :(");
        }
        // ---------------block 1----------------//

        // the same as the above block
        // ---------------block 2----------------//
        SAVE_HOOK = null;
        System.gc();        
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if (SAVE_HOOK != null) {
            SAVE_HOOK.isAlive();
        } else {
            System.out.println("no, i am dead :(");
        }
        // ---------------block 2----------------//
    }
}
```

---

**Result:**

finalize mehtod executed!

yes, i am still alive :)

no, i am dead :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to ask two questions:

1. Why is `SAVE_HOOK` not null after the first block?
2. Why is it null after the second, identical block?

The simple answer to the first question is: Because `System.gc()` triggered the garbage collector, which in turn ran the finalizer, which explicitly reassigns the reference. But I assume you know that already, and what you mean to ask is: Why wasn't the object reclaimed after the finalizer completed?

The answer is in the documentation to [`finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--):

> After the `finalize` method has been invoked for an object, no further action is taken until the Java virtual machine has again determined that there is no longer any means by which this object can be accessed [...] at which point the object may be discarded.

So as long as you still have a strong reference to the object, it will never be garbage collected.

The answer to the second question is: You set it to null and it's never reassigned because the finalizer for a particular instance will only ever run once. This is also in the documentation, right after the previous quote:

> The `finalize` method is never invoked more than once by a Java virtual machine for any given object.

Comment: Since this seems to be a common misunderstanding (or sloppy statement), here a clarification: the garbage collector does not run the finalization. The garbage collector will only *enqueue* objects needing finalization. A JVM may have one or more threads dedicated to finalization which will dequeue the objects and execute the `finalize()` method, but there is no guaranty about whether and when this will eventually happen. There might be a long time between the garbage collector’s detection of an object’s unreachability and its actual finalization.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to this: an object can only be finalized once in its lifetime.   The finalize method can cause the object to escape deletion the first time, but *next time* the object is detected as unreachable, it will simply be deleted.

Comment: Does `System.gc()` invoke the `finalize()` the first time?

Comment: The garbage collector will run `finalize()` on an object the first time that it detects that the object is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

In an object's life lifecycle, it will go through reachable->finalizable->finalized->reclaimed phases. After finalize() method was execute, the object will get in finalized phase, and wait for the next gc trigger, it will be reclaimed. So in the lifecycle, the finalize() method will be exectued only once. Your SAVE_HOOK is a static variable and it was assigned value in finalize() method again. That's why in first if block, it's not null. but the second time, it's dead.

Comment: Does that mean `System.gc()` will implicitly call finalize(), so it doesn't cause `SAVE_HOOK` to be `null`? 

In the overrided finalize() function `FinalizeEscapeGC.SAVE_HOOK = this`, so the `SAVE_HOOK` survives again.

Comment: Calling System.gc() suggests that the JVM expend effort toward recycling unused objects. finalize() method is called by garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.